# How can I run an npm script with a file path in windows?

Tags: npm, terminal, npm-scripts

I am working on a project with a windows machine, and I have a few npm scripts like this:

`"start" : "./foo/bar"`

When I try to run `npm run start` I get this error:

```
.\foo\bar is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I noticed the forward slash has been flipped to a backslash for windows, but also if I run this command on its own the bash terminal will interrupt them as 'escapes' and return:

`bash: .foobar: command not found`

The file runs ok in the terminal if I use `./foo/bar` or `.\\foo\\bar` but not if I use these in the npm script.

What can I do to have this working in Windows? Furthermore is there a way to write it to be compatible for Win/Mac/Linux?

Answer (score 1):

It works when you first do a `cd` with normal slashes (npm/nodejs seems to resolve this depending on the OS), then you only have to specify the file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "not-working": "scripts/another-folder/foo.cmd",
    "working": "cd scripts/another-folder && foo.cmd"
  },
```